# Laravel cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: oauth

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-passport

I get this error on Digital Ocean Ubuntu server after deployment. It works perfectly on Heroku which is our staging server. It is a Laravel project where we use Laravel Passport. How do we solve this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Laravel\Passport\Client as AuthClient;
use Exception;

trait AuthTrait
{
    public function getTokenAndRefreshToken($email, $password)
    {
        try {
            $auth_client = AuthClient::where('password_client', 1)->first();
            $url = env('APP_URL') . "/oauth/token";
            $response = Http::asForm()->post($url, [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => $auth_client->id,
                'client_secret' => $auth_client->secret,
                'username' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
                'scope' => '*'
            ]);
            $result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);


            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is status code .? 404 or 500

Comment: look you're using `env('APP_URL') ` here: its possible that you've run `php artisan config:cache` at one point and then you've lost access to values using `env()`. This is why Laravel recommends getting env values via config. Have you attempted using `config('app.url')` instead of this `env(...)`?

Comment: @KamleshPaul 500